# I am student and new to Python and I have an exam question

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Implement function `triangleArea(a,b,c)` that takes as input the lengths of the 3 sides of a triangle and returns the area of the triangle. By Heron's formula, the area of a triangle with side lengths a, b, and c is
>   `s(s - a)(s -b)(s -c)`
>   , where
>   `s = (a+b+c)/2`.
>
> ```
> >>> triangleArea(2,2,2)
> 1.7320508075688772
> ```

Comment: Hi, sai! Welcome to [SO]. Can you tell us what you've tried so far, and what has gone wrong so far?

Comment: Also, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula#Formulation), your formula is missing a square root.

Comment: Hi Sai, the purpose of StackOverflow is to be a community that answers developer questions as they are developing, debugging, testing, etc. But this looks like you posted a question from your assignment here hoping someone just answers the question. Please avoid this behavior in the future.

Comment: Previous comments covered why this is not a great question for this site. To help you with future questions, please start by taking the [tour], then go over the [help] and concentrate on [ask] and especially on how to provide a [mre]. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

You already had all the equations. You just need to put them in a function, like this:

```
import math

def triangleArea(a, b, c):
    s = (a+b+c)//2
    return math.sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c))
```

Comment: Please don't answer the student's exam questions.

Comment: @chepner No problem. I will refrain from answering exam questions in the future.